What does the smallest possible pairing between a convex set and its polar measure?
Assume that $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact, convex set with $0\in \mathrm{int}(C)$. We define the polar set as $$
C^\ast := \{\, y\in\mathbb{R}^n  \, \mid \, \, \langle x  , y\rangle \leq 1 \, \text{ for all }\, x\in C\}.
$$ Consider the pairing $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle:C\times C^\ast\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ between $C$ and its polar. The convexity of $C$ and $C^\ast$ implies that the image of the pairing must be an interval in $\mathbb{R}$, say $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$. Now, it is clear from the definition of $C^\ast$ that $b=1$. Moreover, the assumption $0\in\mathrm{int}(C)$ implies that $a<0$. My question is the following:

Let's define $p(C):=-a$. What property of the convex set $C$ does $p(C)$ measure?

The following properties can be easily deduced:

$p(\lambda C) = p(C)$ for $\lambda > 0$ and $p(C^\ast)=p(C)$.
If $C=B(0,R)$ is the ball around $0$ with radius $R$, then $p(C)=1$.
If $C$ is squeezed between two balls, say $B(0,r)\subset C\subset B(0,R)$, then $p(C)\leq R/r$. This is an equality for intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.

From these properties, it seems to me like $p(C)$ measures "roundedness" of $C$.
